# How to find out CPU usage of DLLs within an instance of svchost.exe

Tags: cpu-usage, svchost

My Windows Server 2008 R2 should be almost idle, yet it's taking about 12-15% CPU almost all the time.  The busy process is an instance of svchost.exe

Using SvcHost Process Analyser, I've established that the services running in this process are as shown:

[image]

However, I don't know which is (or are) contributing to the CPU usage.

How do I get more detail?

Answer (score 0):

You could try Process Monitor from here;

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

It'll give you a decent granular view of processes on your server.